# How access variable request/ response in another file js

Tags: javascript, nodes, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a lot of function in my index.js for my webhook, and i wish split functions to different js files to my code is more clean.

I have not problem to use agent, but I don't know how I can have an access of variable "request" (to have the parameters receipt) in another file.

I tried this :

**Index.js**

```js
// See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
// for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const { Payload } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const Test = require("./Test"); //File with an function

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  
  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }
}

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set("intent-test", Test.welcome);
  intentMap.set("intent-test", fallback);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

**Test.js**

```js
exports.welcome = (agent) => {
    agent.add("Hello World !");
    console.log(request); // How can I have a access to the variable "request" / "response
};
```

Do you have a solution please ?

Comment: If the answer helped somehow consider upvoting/accepting

Answer (score 0):

While I understand that you are not having any problems with your agent, there are some [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-inline-editor#limits) when using the DialogFlow Inline editor. As you can see below, one of the limitations is that you can only work with two files: **index.js** and **package.json**. That means that all your Fulfillments should be inside your index.js file and you can't split it in more files.

[image]